# BinarySearch limits for numbers within range

Tags: c#, binary-search

This is my code:

```
SortedDictionary<int,int> Numbers = new SortedDictionary<int,int>();
List<int> onlyP = new List<int>(Numbers.Keys);
int Inferior = int.Parse(toks[0]);
int Superior = int.Parse(toks[1]);
int count = 0;

int inferiorindex = Array.BinarySearch(Numbers.Keys.ToArray(), Inferior);
if (inferiorindex < 0) inferiorindex = (inferiorindex * -1) - 1;
int superiorindex = Array.BinarySearch(Numbers.Keys.ToArray(), Superior);
if (superiorindex < 0) superiorindex = (superiorindex * -1) - 1;

count = Numbers[onlyP[superiorindex]] - Numbers[onlyP[inferiorindex]];
```

So what I'm trying to do is this: I've got a sorted dictionary with powers as keys, and a normal iteration as values. I've to print how many numbers of the keys fit within a specified range.

Example: 
Some entries of the dict: [1,1],[4,2],[8,3],[9,4],[16,5],[25,6],[27,7],[32,8]
Limits: 2 and 10
Numbers within 2 - 10 : 4, 8, 9 = 3 numbers.

With BinarySearch I'm trying to quickly find the numbers I want and then substract Potencias[onlyP[superiorindex]] - Potencias[onlyP[inferiorindex]] to find how many numbers are within the range. Unfortunately it's not working for all the cases, and it sometimes gives less numbers than the actual amount. How can this be fixed? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] Examples of the problems: If I select limits: 4 and 4... it returns 0, but the answer is 1. 
limits: 1 and 10^9 (the whole range) returns 32669... But the answer is 32670. 
The algorithm is ignoring powers.

Comment: Any questions I'll answer them here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry some code was missing, just edited.

Comment: Why is it not just superiorIndex - inferiorIndex? Why the look ups in the dictionary in the last line of the code?

Comment: @ChristianHorsdal I did it that way because the first item has index 0. But as a matter of fact I haven't tried that yet, thanks for the spot.

Comment: It made the code look better and indeed less execution time because of the look ups, but the problems are still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, having read the documentation. Notice the -1 on the upperIndex conversion and the +1 on the return value, these are important.

```
var numbers = new[] { 1, 4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32 };

var lowerBound = 4;
var upperBound = 17;

int lowerIndex = Array.BinarySearch(numbers, lowerBound);
if (lowerIndex < 0) lowerIndex = ~lowerIndex;

// - 1 here because we want the index of the item that is <= upper bound.
int upperIndex = Array.BinarySearch(numbers, upperBound);
if (upperIndex < 0) upperIndex = ~upperIndex - 1;

return (upperIndex - lowerIndex) + 1;
```

**Explanation**:

For the lower index we just take the complement because the BinarySearch returns the index of the first item >= lowerBound.

For the upper index we additionally minus one from the complement because we want the first item <= upperBound (not >= upperBound which is what BinarySearch returns).

Comment: That is why he's using the BinarySearch ;-) It's a mean to get the closest item in the collection if the searched element isn't present by itself.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand the problem now, will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, limits might or might not be a power so I use binary search. I tried to iterate through the dict but it's slow compared to this method and I really need speed in this algorithm.

Comment: @Joey : have a look at the msdn link in my answer, it does exactly that, combining the result with some bitwise operator stuff. Just read the manual ;-)

Comment: It finally worked! Thanks a lot! I have to understand the code better because to be honest I'm a bit confused.

Comment: No problem, if you tell me what's confusing you I'll do my best to explain.

Comment: Why I do (if (lowerIndex < 0) lowerIndex = ~lowerIndex;) in the lowerbound and in the upperbound I do (if (upperIndex < 0) upperIndex = ~upperIndex - 1;) substracting 1? I mean how did that simple move solved my issue?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're not doing it the wright way for post processing the binary search return value :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kwds4b1.aspx

Should be :
`if (inferiorindex < 0) inferiorindex = ~inferiorindex;`

(untested)

Moreover, List supports a binary search, so you don't have to do the Array.BinarySearch thing, just work on `onlyP`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know lists supported BS. I just fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried the bitwise operator instead of `inferiorindex = (inferiorindex * -1) - 1` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
int inferiorindex = Array.BinarySearch<int>(keys, Inferior);
if (inferiorindex < 0) {
    inferiorindex = ~inferiorindex;
}

int superiorindex = Array.BinarySearch<int>(keys, Superior);
if (superiorindex < 0) {
    // superiorindex is the binary complement of the next higher.
    // -1 because we want the highest.
    superiorindex = ~superiorindex - 1;
}

int count = superiorindex - inferiorindex + 1;
```

Comment: It finally worked! Thanks a lot! I have to understand the code better because to be honest I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Look at the description of [Array.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cy9f6wb.aspx) and use the debugger in order to analyse the code step by step.